# "This site can’t be reached" Docker container on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, digital-ocean

I have this React/Nodejs application which I'm trying to deploy it on Digital Ocean using Docker. I've created a Docker Droplet with 2GB RAM, cloned the project and trying to run it.

By now, I'm not getting any error logs when building the image and running it. But, when I try to access it I get the error in the browser "This site can’t be reached".

I'm building my image like this: `docker build -t myImage .`

And runnig it and passing my env variables like this:

`docker run -p 80:3000 -e NODE_ENV="production" -e MONGO_URI="URI" -e SECRET_OR_KEY="KEY" myImage`

Everything seems to be working fine (build and running). I get the log that my mongodb connected and the server is running. But I can't actually see the application.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.10.0

WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN git clone https://github.com/repo.git

WORKDIR /usr/src/project

RUN npm install
WORKDIR /usr/src/project/client
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /usr/src/project

EXPOSE 80 3000

ENTRYPOINT npm run server
```

I've created this based on another application that runs on Digital Ocean as well.

And this is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');


//Route files
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const fpsos = require('./routes/api/fpsos');
const bids = require('./routes/api/bids');
const news = require('./routes/api/news');

const app = express();

//Body parser middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json ());

//DB config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
    .connect(db)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

//Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/news', news);
app.use('/api/fpso', fpsos);
app.use('/api/bid', bids);


// Server static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
```

What am I missing here? I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have docker listening on port 3000, but you appear to have your NodeJS app listening to port 5000 unless you are passing a PORT environment variable somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CoolestNerdIII. Indeed, It is running on 5000 (I think I was having the react port in mind when trying to run it). I changed the parameters of my run command and now I see an error log in my container when I try to reach the page. But I'm getting this error now: `'/usr/src/project/client/build/index.html'`. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: This error appears to be based on the `res.sendFile` where you are returning the index.html file. I would suggest that you either try and run the docker container locally to confirm the path, or you can try and put an absolute path to see if that resolves the issue, but effectively it appears to be that the file is not found.

Comment: Yes, my build was actually not being run during the image building. I adjusted that and now everything is working perfectly in the server. Thank you very much @CoolestNerdIII

Comment: Awesome! I will provide my comments in the answer, just so that others can know what solved it.

Comment: I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have docker listening on a port different (5000) from your node application (3000), which is why node will not return any data to the browser.